# Created a mouseover zoom effect on an image, first its blurry, then sharp

Tags: html, css, zooming, mouseover

I added the class `.fader`. it all works fine but after it zoomes on the pic, its gets blurry first, then sharpened later. I want it sharp from the beginning what can I do?

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 fader">
   <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="images/graphicxtemplate4bw.jpg" alt="" onMouseOver= src="images/graphicxtemplate4.jpg" onMouseOut= src="images/graphicxtemplate4bw.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fader {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.fader img {
    line-height: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.fader img:hover {
    opacity: 0.95;
    transform: scale(1.12);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem blurry to me? https://jsfiddle.net/6xanxvbt/

Answer (score -1):

What about using `CSS3 transform` property and use `scale` which ill give a zoom like effect, this can be done like so,

**Html**

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
    <img  src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="Some awesome text"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

Here's a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27Syr/1206/). I removed some of the element to make it simpler, you can always add overflow hidden to the `.image` to hide the overflow of the scaled image.

> zoom property only works in IE